# c++ add array with size of int variable

Tags: c++, arrays

I have this problem that Visual C++ does not let me use the method parameter as the size for an array I want to create. What am I doing wrong and how can this be done?

```
 void feld_links_rotieren(char a[], unsigned int n, unsigned int shift)
{
    shift = shift % n;

if (shift == 0)
{
    // Verschiebung um 0 Plätze ist zulässig. Funktion wird sofort verlassen.
    return;
}

// Ersten Teil isolieren
char first_half[shift];
```

...

Comment: TL;DR: Use `std::vector`

Comment: it's for university and i am not allowed to use anything else than an array

Comment: My condolences. Your teachers belong to the school of taught that argues for learning only half of the C++ language. You'll need to use dynamic memory allocation yourself.

Comment: *It's for university and i am not allowed to use anything else than an array* -- Well go back to your university and ask them what to do, since arrays in C++ cannot be declared using a variable for the number of entries.

Comment: YAIT (yet another incompetent teacher)

Comment: Unfortunately the salary of programming teachers is not adequate for programmers. So programming is taught by non-programmers.